# How to use FORMAT() on SUM() in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, formatting, decimal

I want to use `FORMAT` on the result of `SUM` to produce a currency style format with commas and no decimal places.

I'm trying the following using MySQL 5.7:

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(SUM(x.07_17 / fx.07_17), 0) AS total
```

#### Issue

The problem is this changes the text-output drastically.

- Without the format, I get the correct result of SUM: `350914`.
- With the format in place, I get only the first 3 numbers: `350`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As [MySQL defined](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format): `If the given decimal position is 0, it rounds to return no decimal point or fractional part. You can optionally specify a locale value to format numbers to the pattern appropriate for the given region.`

Comment: What are the values for `x.07_17` and `fx.07_17` ? What is your expected output-format? Please give an example like "I want `350,914` where the comma is a thousands-separator".

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation to see how each parameters works for the FORMAT function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_format

This query shows you different style to display your data  [(Sql fiddle example)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/28383)

```
SELECT SUM(c1 / c2)                                   AS total1
     , CONCAT(FORMAT(SUM(c1 / c2), 3, 'fr_FR'), ' €') AS total2
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(SUM(c1 / c2), 3))           total3
FROM   ( SELECT 148277 c1
              , 5.1561 c2 ) t
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the FORMAT() function in MySQL then it adds thousands separators and a decimal separator as required.
Example
In MySQL, the FORMAT() function accepts a number as the first argument, followed by the decimal position:

SELECT FORMAT(123456.789, 2);
Result:

123,456.79

Refere to this page: [How to Format Numbers with Commas in MySQL](https://database.guide/how-to-format-numbers-with-commas-in-mysql/)

Comment: To pass a non-0 second argument to `FORMAT()` was already answered Apr 16, 2018 by Kobi. What does your answer add to that? What about adding the supportive tutorial-link to this answer, either via comment or suggest and edit there.